# Как динамически выделять память при подключении модели с большим количеством строк

Tags: qt, qt5

Есть наследник `QAbstractTableModel`, в котором переопределен виртуальный метод `QAbstarctTableModel::rowCount`. 
Как я понимаю при подключении к `QTableView` данной модели выделяется память для всех строк сразу. Как этого избежать? Хочу, чтобы память была выделена только для видимых строк

Comment: Можно использовать [QAbstractItemModel::fetchMore](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-fetchmore-example.html)

Comment: @maestro спасибо, ваш комментарий помог

Answer (score -1):

Ничего никому не выделяется. Надо еще переопределить data() и она должна отдавать данные для запрошенной ячейки. А из памяти они будут или вы их случайно генерить будете, это ваше дело.